# Keras ImageDataGenerator vs bounding boxes

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to implement custom object detection by taking a trained YOLOv2 model in Keras, removing the last layer and retraining it with new data. I'm confused about how to feed the data to Keras, though. I have annotated a bunch of pictures with bounding boxes using the YOLO annotation, and put them in two separate folders (`images` where the .jpgs reside and `annots` where the .txt annotations are).

I also removed the last layer from the model and added a custom one (I'm trying to predict bounding boxes for 2 classes).

I'm trying to pass my data with an ImageDataGenerator, as my dataset is quite small.

Since I am trying to create bounding boxes (and thus have categories AND bounding boxes as target variables), does the ImageDataGenerator also somehow skew the bounding boxes? Or in this case can/should I not use the ImageDataGenerator (because if it rotates the pictures but does not do so with the bounding boxes, it might mess up the learning)